# want to convert a string into array

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a string like this -

```
[answer] => 8|$0-$100,000<>9|$3-$100,000<>10|$2-$100,000.
```

I want it into an array like this:-

```
[answer] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0-100,000
        [1] => 3-100,000
        [2] => 2-100,000
    )
```

Comment: use explode function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this;

```
$answer = "8|$0-$100,000<>9|$3-$100,000<>10|$2-$100,000";

$answer = preg_replace("^[0-9]*\|^", "", $answer); // remove the number and |
$answer = str_replace("$", "", $answer); // remove $ sign 
$answer = explode("<>", $answer);
```

Comment: thanks weirdo..its working

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job.

```
 $string = [answer];
 $string_array = explode("<>", $string);
 foreach($string_array as &$arr){
   $arr = substr($arr, 0, strpos('$'));
   $arr = str_replace('$', '', $arr);
 }

 var_dump($string_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job.

```
    $r = "8|$0-$100,000<>9|$3-$100,000<>10|$2-$100,000";
    $array = explode('<>', $r);
    foreach ($array as &$val) {
        $val = preg_replace("/^[0-9]+|/", "", $val);
        $val = str_replace(array('|', '$'), '', $val);
    }
    var_dump($array);
```